# Error while using HttpConnection

Tags: java, android

**QUESTION**

I am trying to parse an XML file from a website. I am using an HTTP connection for getting the XML content from the website. While I am downloading the content I am facing some issues. The code is given below.

**CODE**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

}
public void process(View view)  {
    Thread thread=new Thread(new Download());
    thread.start();



}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public class Download implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml");
            HttpURLConnection connection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.getDoOutput();
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, stream + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
} }
```

This is the code I am using to download the content. The error I am getting is

**ERROR**

```
10-21 01:14:21.459  25125-25181/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "api.androidhive.info": No address associated with hostname
10-21 01:14:21.459  25125-25181/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
10-21 01:14:21.459  25125-25181/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
10-21 01:14:21.459  25125-25181/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
10-21 01:14:21.459  25125-25181/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
10-21 01:14:21.459  25125-25181/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
10-21 01:14:21.459  25125-25181/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
10-21 01:14:21.459  25125-25181/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
10-21 01:14:21.459  25125-25181/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
10-21 01:14:21.459  25125-25181/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
10-21 01:14:21.459  25125-25181/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
10-21 01:14:21.459  25125-25181/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
10-21 01:14:21.459  25125-25181/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
10-21 01:14:21.459  25125-25181/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
10-21 01:14:21.459  25125-25181/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
10-21 01:14:21.459  25125-25181/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ at com.example.sajithm.domparsing.MainActivity$Download.run(MainActivity.java:65)
10-21 01:14:21.459  25125-25181/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
10-21 01:14:21.459  25125-25181/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
10-21 01:14:21.459  25125-25181/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
10-21 01:14:21.459  25125-25181/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
10-21 01:14:21.459  25125-25181/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
10-21 01:14:21.459  25125-25181/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ ... 15 more
    --------- beginning of /dev/log/system
10-21 01:19:34.259  25125-25131/com.example.sajithm.domparsing D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 306K, 4% free 9003K/9336K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
```

**REQUEST**
The web address is valid. Can anyone please suggest a solution to tackle this problem. Is there any other way to download the content?

Comment: Its possible for me to access the site. I can even see the content of the file.

Comment: Maybe it was temporarily down.  In any case, you should handle this error gracefully because it might happen again.

Comment: ok. Is there any other way to download the components from the site

Comment: Could you please suggest  me a valid side which is having xml content.

Comment: check if your connection is slow

Comment: check this link--- https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22nome%2C%20ak%22)&format=xml&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys

Comment: My connection is fast. I can browse stuffs in high speed

Comment: @RajSharma    I am getting the error even using the link u have given.

Comment: dummy xml : [codehelp](http://www.codehelp.co.uk/xml/codehelp2.xsl)

Comment: if still there is problem then there is problem in your code ....provide full code of Download thread class

Comment: Please put the logcat in a code block too. They are unreadable now. And certainly do not put errors in comments.

Comment: 10-21 01:41:57.159    4883-4910/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.codehelp.co.uk": No address associated with hostname
10-21 01:41:57.159    4883-4910/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
10-21 01:41:57.159    4883-4910/com.example.sajithm.domparsing W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
10-21 01:41:57.163    4883-4910/com.example.sajithm.domparsing

Comment: 'Unable to resolve host "api.androidhive.info":'. That is your whole problem. Te DNS cannot resolve your host.

Comment: @greenapps  How can i tackle this problem.

Comment: 'Its possible for me to access the site.'. But how? Using a browser on your PC? That will not do. You should try a browser on your device/phone/tablet. Tell what you do exactly please.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below code and it worked :

Method to make a call :

```
 public void makeXMLRequest() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.getDoOutput();
            String readStream = readStream(con.getInputStream());
            // Give output for the command line
            System.out.println(readStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Reference method to parse response :

```
 private static String readStream(InputStream in) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));) {

            String nextLine = "";
            while ((nextLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(nextLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

How to call this method :

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                makeXMLRequest();
            }
        });

        thread.start();
```

Try this if it can help.

Thanks..!

Comment: The same error is showing again and again. I am doing this code for android minimum version 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Though you can access the website by web browser of your computer. I can access the link as well.
But it doesn't mean your Android phone can resolve the domain name.
Please use adb shell to try

```
ping api.androidhive.info
```

You will most probably see a negative response.

Comment: Can you suggest a solution for this problem

Comment: Have you tried the ping? What is the result? The possible reasons for not working DNS client on Android includes using VPN, firewall policy and etc.

Comment: Sir you are correct. The problem is with my emulator. I reinstalled genymotion. Now everything works fine.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with emulator. In some cases emulator cannot access websites though the site is accessible through our pc browser. I reinstalled the virtual device (In my case it was Nexus 4.3) inside Genymotion,now everything works fine and the emulator is capable to access all websites.

Thank you